# Get-ADUser - output a blank line fo CSV file when no data is found

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I've cobbled together (from various online sources) a script that can return data about AD users from a CSV file. It can clearly mark when a user has NOT been found, but perhaps just as important to me is a way of outputting a blank line to the CSV file when the input CSV file also has a blank. That would save a lot mucking around in Excel to make sure that all the blank lines correspond to each other (and subsequently where user data has been found). A 1-to-1 comparsion is the goal.

Here is what I have...

```
$ImportCSV = "C:\Users\x\Desktop\testCSV_in.csv"


$Names = Import-Csv -Path $ImportCSV

$Results = foreach ($Name in $Names) {
    $filter = $Name.samAccountName
    
    $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$filter'" -Properties Samaccountname, Givenname, Surname, EmailAddress, Name

    #blank lines input CSV
    if ( $User.SamAccountName -eq ""  ) {
        # please help
    }

    # found user
    if ( $User ) {
        $User |
        Select-Object -Property Samaccountname, Givenname, Surname, EmailAddress, Name            
    }

    # not found user
    else {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = 'MISSING ACCOUNT'

        }
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\x\Desktop\testCSV_out.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

All the possible combinations that I can think of for `$User.SamAccountName -eq ""` just return back a CSV file that doesn't reflect the gaps that I purposely introduced (to mimic real use-cases).

I am sure, it's a just a line or two code that's needed. Thanks.

Comment: Put the `$user = get-aduser....` inside of an `if` statement --> `if ($filter) { $user = get-aduser.... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a normalized export you need a normalized Object, meaning, all columns for your CSV must exist for all lines, even if they're `$null`. Try this code, see if it works:

```bash
$out = {
    param($samAccountName)

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Samaccountname = $samAccountName
        Givenname      = $User.GivenName
        Surname        = $User.SurName
        EmailAddress   = $User.EmailAddress
        Name           = $User.Name
    }
}

Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\testCSV_in.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.samAccountName)) {
        return & $out -samAccountName 'User Not Found on CSV'
    }
    $params = @{
        Properties = 'Samaccountname', 'Givenname', 'Surname', 'EmailAddress', 'Name'
        LDAPFilter = "(SamAccountName={0})" -f $_.samAccountName
    }
    $user = Get-ADUser @params

    if(-not $user) {
        return & $out -samAccountName 'User Not Found on AD'
    }

    & $out -samAccountName $user.samAccountName
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\x\Desktop\testCSV_out.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Edit: `Import-Csv`, same as `ConvertFrom-Csv` will skip empty lines. At least one column has to be populated.

Comment: Hi! I've just given that a try. Most of it works, but any empty lines in the input CSV file are not reflected at all in the output CSV.

Comment: I'm back home trying it in a test AD environment I'll reduce the number of fields and give it another try.

Comment: Well but you're using `Import-Csv` empty lines will never be taken as literal using it. See my edit as example. At least one of the columns has to be populated to be converted as object in PS.

Comment: OK, cool. It looks like not much can be done about it. I can use a workaround in Excel to replace any blanks in the input with something that will at least return a value in the output CSV. Thanks for your help @santisq

Comment: if you really need to check for empty lines, a possibility is using `get-content` and a foreach line in the content if there is a line split in commas but seems like a lot of work for something so simple.

Answer (score -3):

I found a way to get this same functionality and also add manager email and calculated fields as well:

```
    Import-CSV C:\test\CSV_in.csv |
 ForEach-Object {
     Try{
         $u = Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties * -ErrorAction Stop | Select GivenName, Surname, samaccountname, Title, Department, @{N='Manager';E={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name}},@{N="ManagerEmail";E={(Get-ADUser -Property emailaddress $_.Manager).emailaddress}}
         [PSCustomObject]@{User = $_.name; samaccountname = $u.samaccountname; Manager = $u.Manager; ManagerEmail = $u.ManagerEmail}
     }
     Catch{
         [PSCustomObject]@{User = $_.name; samaccountname = 'Not Found'; Manager = 'N/A'; ManagerEmail = 'N/A'}
     }
 } | Export-CSV c:\test\CSV_out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```